# First Python program, "lotto prediction"

Tags: python

I am trying to make a lotto program.  Its pick 3, numbers 0-9, Choose three numbers from 0-0-0 to 9-9-9. I would like to add all numbers that has been called in the past to a variable or tuple. This variable or tuple is checked before printing results.  This is what i got so far.

```
import random
items = range (10)
random.sample([items]), 3
[4, 0, 2]    # result
```

How do I setup a variable with the numbers results of past draw and print results based on most called?

Comment: I don't see any actual question.

Comment: It is "import random", not "Import random". Capitalization is important.

Comment: Are you sure you wish to use `random.sample(items, 3)`? `random.sample` will pick 3 *unique* numbers from `items` and bind them as a tuple. So by doing this, you are taking away the possibility to get tuples like (1,1,1) or (2,2,3).

Comment: What do you suggest I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get 5 uniqe numbers

```
import random

items = range(10)

results = []

while len(results) < 5:
    number = random.sample(items, 3)
    if number not in results:
        results.append(number)

print results

[[2, 6, 3], [8, 0, 4], [0, 3, 4], [7, 8, 6], [2, 6, 9]]
```

---

Get 1000 not uniqe numbers and get 3 most common results

```
import random
import collections

items = range(10)

results = collections.Counter()

for __ in range(1000):
    number = random.sample(items, 3)
    results.update([tuple(number)])

print results.most_common(3)

[((2, 0, 6), 6), ((5, 4, 9), 6), ((1, 0, 3), 5)]
```

I got:

(2, 0, 6) - 6 times,
(5, 4, 9) - 6 times,
(1, 0, 3) - 5 times,

---

**EDIT:**

With numbers `000`, `111`, `222` and grouped by number of drawn.

```
import random
import collections

results = collections.Counter()

for __ in range(50):
    digit1 = random.randint(0,9)
    digit2 = random.randint(0,9)
    digit3 = random.randint(0,9)
#    results.update([(digit1,digit2,digit3)])
    results.update([ '%d%d%d' % (digit1,digit2,digit3) ])

#print results

print
print '3 most common numbers:', results.most_common(3)

print
print '3 most common numbers:'
for x in results.most_common(3):
    print '%s - %d times' % x

grouped_results = {}

for number, times in results.items():
    if times not in grouped_results:
        grouped_results[times] = []
    grouped_results[times].append(number)

print
print 'grouped results:', grouped_results


for times, numbers in grouped_results.items():
    print
    print 'drawn %d time(s):' % times
    print numbers
```

results:

```
3 most common numbers: [('152', 2), ('799', 2), ('088', 2)]

3 most common numbers:
152 - 2 times
799 - 2 times
088 - 2 times

grouped results: {1: ['458', '603', '335', '660', '012', '750', '396', '177', '176', '399', '497', '231', '254', '641', '694', '956', '322', '938', '918', '917', '586', '587', '584', '140', '069', '082', '299', '779', '617', '462', '025', '267', '169', '226', '084', '840', '909', '537', '929', '350', '824', '513'], 2: ['152', '799', '088', '261']}

drawn 1 time(s):
['458', '603', '335', '660', '012', '750', '396', '177', '176', '399', '497', '231', '254', '641', '694', '956', '322', '938', '918', '917', '586', '587', '584', '140', '069', '082', '299', '779', '617', '462', '025', '267', '169', '226', '084', '840', '909', '537', '929', '350', '824', '513']

drawn 2 time(s):
['152', '799', '088', '261']
```

Comment: HI thanks for your help.  I would like to develop on this a little further.  I am trying to create a variable where all previous winning numbers are stored.  Based on that I would like a list of 10 or 20 numbers that could be called next.  So from the list of previously drawn numbers the most common are printed or coupled together (ex.  1 was drawn 5 times, while 2 was drawn 4 times, while 3 was drawn 3 times. so 1,2,3 will b placed together) Also need to get repeating numbers 111, 222, 004 etc.